# Using pipes/stdin/stdout in systemd

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service that runs a one off script using an "ExecStart" directive.  The script runs early in the boot process (before filesystem mounting) as it loads ZFS encryption keys.

Because of the way I am doing this (keys decrypted from TPM rather than stored on the disk) I have to pipe the output of one command to another.  I have tried to work out why this is failing and I can see that when I run a command which is supposed to write to /dev/stdout I am getting an "Unable to open output file" error.

If I run the same service with "systemd start <servicename>" after the machine has booted, it succeeds without error.  I assume therefore this is a unit dependency problem. I have no idea what unit I might be missing though.

(I am not using an encrypted root fs, so this is not a root filesystem bootstrapping problem.)

Comment: Does this [bugreport](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1212756) explain your case?

Comment: I'd seen that, but I don't think so.   I am definitely not using a socket.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a misleading error message thrown up by tpm_unsealdata.  The actual problem was that tcsd was not loaded. It turns out that in the unit file

```
Requires=trousers
```

Will not load the pre-requisite before running the unit script and

```
After=trousers
```

is also required.

(Yes the TPM1 tcsd daemon is in part of a package called "trousers".)

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.